# Flutter response after scan

Tags: flutter

I need help regrading the scan using qr_code_scanner, the scanner successful but don't know how to call response either success or not. here example.

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
this.controller = controller;
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
  controller.pauseCamera();
  var response = await ScanApi.scan(scanData.code);
  print(response);
  result = scanData;
  setState(() {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("check"),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Data: ${scanData.code}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ).then((value) => controller.resumeCamera());
```

and my example api post to get reponse.

```
 static Future<dynamic> scan() async {
final url = Uri.parse(url);
final response = await http.post(url);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final String msg = json.decode(response.body)["status"];
  print(msg);
  return msg;
  
} else {
  throw Exception();
}}
```

Comment: The two examples are not related to each other, as the scan point is a different thing from the API request, so please explain more so I can help

Comment: the api scan class is ScanApi , my problem is how to get return msg after scan.

Answer (score 1):

code like this and calling this class into widget.

```
    class ScanResponse {
  String status;

  ScanResponse({this.status});

  factory ScanResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return ScanResponse(
      status: jsonData['status'],
    );
  }
}
```